# Multiselect Jquery plugin issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Chosen jquery library. The values selected are stored in an array and then loaded again later on. The values that get loaded are correct, but the order of selection is incorrect. 
For example, if i selection option3 and then option2, the order is option2, option3 when reloaded.

html:

```
<select id="second" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">    
     <option value=""></option> 
     <option value="United States">United States</option>
     <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
     <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
     <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
     <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
     <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option> 
     <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option> 
     <option value="Angola">Angola</option> 
     <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
var selectedOptions = [];
$('button').click(function(){
    //$(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
  $('#second_chosen ul li span').each(function(i, selected){
      selectedOptions[i] = $(selected).text();
  });
  //clear the selection
  $("#second").val("").trigger("chosen:updated");

});

$('#previousBtn').click(function(){
    console.log(selectedOptions);
    $("#second").val(selectedOptions).trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

The order of selection is correct in selectedOptions array, but it displays in the order of the options, instead of order of selection.

Please find jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Da4m3/1051/. 
Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: If the issue comes after saving the selected list, then you have check in which order the saved result is.

Comment: In the console.log, it's in right order, So now have to check in select box.

Comment: but why you use `previous` button ?

Comment: I think OP, by mistake written `Previous` in place of `Preview.`

Comment: It is not the job of select fields, whether native ones or such a replacement, to implement any “order” of choices …

Comment: Try checking [this](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/813) and related answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the below link helps.

[Chosen: Keep Multiple Selection Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395503/chosen-keep-multiple-selection-order)

https://github.com/tristanjahier/chosen-order

There is a plugin for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I used **push()** function to add values to **selectedOptions** array

```
$('#second_chosen ul li span').each(function(i, selected){
    selectedOptions.push($(selected).text());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Da4m3/1096/

Answer (score 0):

the point is, the entries in array are not shown in the same order in the select